# Golang - GORM how to create a model for an existing table?

Tags: go-gorm

According to the source from this link : https://gorm.io/docs/index.html

To declaring a model, we do this:

```
type User struct {
  ID           uint
  Name         string
  Email        *string
  Age          uint8
  Birthday     *time.Time
  MemberNumber sql.NullString
  ActivatedAt  sql.NullTime
  CreatedAt    time.Time
  UpdatedAt    time.Time
}
```

Then run `migration` to create it on the database.

However, I could not find any document mentioning about declaring a model that already exist in database. I suppose there is something like this:

```
type User struct {
  ID           uint
  Name         string


This_struct(User).belongs_to_an_existing_table_named("a_table_name")  -- this is an example to explaning what I mean
```

If and only if we do it by declaring a `struct` with the same name with an existing table. Can I change the name for simplicity in my code ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply implement the [`Tabler`](https://pkg.go.dev/gorm.io/gorm@v1.20.12/schema#Tabler) interface as specified [in the docs](https://gorm.io/docs/conventions.html#TableName). Like this:

```
func (User) TableName() string {
  return "a_table_name"
}
```